# What is the technical difference between a formal and informal power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

In my lecture notes the professor wrote that $$e^x = \Sigma \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

is a formal power series because we can plug in whatever we want in $x$ and both side will equate

This is an obvious conclusion, I wonder what he means by formal power series and when is a power series considered informal.

Comment: you should check probably see the wiki page on this topic it is quite informative

Comment: The power series of the type $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+ \ldots $ is referred to as a formal power series.

Comment: I don't dare to post an answer, but I believe the thing is that to make sense of a power series you need to have a notion of *convergence*, which isn't always defined when working in an algebraic setting. To solve this you define a formal power series as a "symbolic" power series without worrying about convergence issues, but still being able to work with their algebraic properties.

Comment: For an introduction to formal power series see the first chapter of Peter Henrici's *Applied and computational complex analysis*.

Comment: I think a formal power series is one that doesn't (necessarily) converge where as a mere power series must converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A formal power series is a power series where the question of convergence is not considered.  So a formal power series is just a sequence with a funny notation.  We can write down things like $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k!x^k.$$ This series doesn't converge anywhere except at $x = 0$, but it's perfectly well defined as a *formal* power series.

I think you would have to ask your professor precisely what he means in this context.  It doesn't really make sense to say things like "this power series is a formal power series because it has such and such properties...".  To say it's a formal power series just means that we are going to write down the symbols $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ whether it converges or not.  Strictly speaking, I think you would define all power series to be formal power series, and then for any particular power series you can ask whether it converges anywhere or not.

Answer (score 2):

A formal power series is a power series where you don't care about convergence (or even really what "$x$" is). For example, $$1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$ is a formal power series, including for $x\geq 1$ (where it wouldn't converge) or $x$ not even defined! You can think of it as just an infinite tuple, the $x^n$ are just placeholders.

You'll see this a lot in math. "Formal" usually means symbol pushing. For another related example in some special equations called SPDEs, you'll have "formal" definitions. For example, KPZ is "formally defined" as $\partial_t u=\partial_{xx} u+(\partial_x u)^2-\infty+\xi$. Obviously "$-\infty$" isn't really what's going on, the reality is much more subtle. But we may "formally" write down a bunch of symbols.

No one says "informal", at least not that I have heard of. Formal=writing down the symbols without really caring what they mean, if the object exists, etc.

Edit: for a related example, you can talk about "formal" derivatives. For example, if you are in some weird ring with no concepts of differentiability, you may write the "formal derivative" of $x^n$ as $nx^{n-1}$. For example if you're in $\mathbb{Z}/4$, the derivative of $2x^2$ is $4x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+ \cdots$, where the $a_n$ are arbitrary real (or complex) numbers, might not have a meaningful value except in the very limited case $x=0$ (when of course it equals $a_0$). For example, consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n.$ nevertheless, one can perform *formal* algebraic operations on such series, such as addition and multiplication, to produce other such series, by the same rules that apply for series that converge for a nontrivial range of the $x$ variable. These formal series cannot be regarded as functions, like the series for (e.g.) e$^x$. However, they can be given a meaningful mathematical definition as *sequences*: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is identified with the sequence $(a_0,a_1,...)$, and addition and multiplication are performed on these sequences just as for power series. Thus $$(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}+(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}=(a_n+b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$ and $$(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}=\left( \sum_{j=0}^na_jb_{n-j}\right)_{\!n\in\Bbb N}.$$